# I can't disable find a phone on my iphone 5

Tags: iphone

My iphone got wet and although it is switched off and the sim card is removed, it is still showing as online on icloud so I can't disable the find my phone to enable me to claim on the insurance.  If I erase the phone from icloud, (by clicking on the x next to the device) what does that mean to my data on my phone when I replace my phone?  Does this action of deleting the device from icloud just mean that I have only disabled the find my phone app?

Comment: Use the erase iPhone feature from iCloud.

Comment: see http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702

Comment: Actually... you just made me go look at the interface, I don't even see the X to remove the device from the findmyiphone section of iCloud.

Comment: hmm… it only appears for devices that are offline. My old phone is still on my list, so i could compare. *Edit:* ahh… follow instructions for "Remove an iOS device you no longer have"

Answer (score 2):

When you are not able to remove the iPhone from Find my Iphone in iCloud, try turning on the device and then try to disable Find My iPhone with a mac or pc.

When you erase the iPhone via iCloud, all your settings will be deleted. To place all your data on a new iPhone, you need an iCloud backup or iTunes Backup.

Contacts, photo's, mail, ... Are synced to iCloud by default when logged in on an iDevice. Logging in to iCloud on a new device will fetch all data from iCloud and place it in your photo's, mail, agenda, contacts, ...